# writing admin pages using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am going to create a couple asp.net pages with login page. I am thinking about Forms authentication. The users are around 1000 to 5000. What is the best way to achieve this? I appreciate any help.

Thanks..

Comment: The best way is to start trying, and then ask when you get a specific problem.  Asking StackOverflow to create your project from scratch for you is rarely a good way to get answers, I'm afraid.  You might want to start with the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Without details on exactly what your security requirements are it's going to be impossible for anyone to answer.  There are several different standard security mechanisms available to a .Net app; in addition to the ability to roll your own.  For each there are up and down sides.

Answer (score 0):

Form Authentication with SQL Server is a good idea. Its flexible, but if you want full control you best bet is to come up with a custom solution for your 5k users.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx is good place to start reading up on form authentication with SQL server. We used it once, but it become a bottle neck when the project went global. We implemented our own Authentication Database.